# How to make a list out of a structure in racket?

Tags: list, structure, racket

I made an structure (struct g( a b c d))
and I define it as  (define per (g 1 6 5 4))

however I want to use per as a list argument for another function I want to define.. it gives me an error

> first: contract violation   expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
>   given: #

how can I make per a list with arguments of a structure? or there is no other ways of making something similar.

Answer (score 1):

When you are making a `struct` it's very much like objects in other languages. You have a struct "g" with 4 named slots. Eg. you access the first with `(g-a struct-var)` and so on.

If you want a list then make a list. If you need to make a list from a `g` you need to do something like `(list (g-a x) (g-b x) (g-c x) (g-d x))` and to do the opposite you do `(apply g lst)`

Comment: thanks for your reply, so for doing the opposite if I have a list (define list '(1 2 3 4))

Comment: @JJ12 It's not wise to use `list` as a variable as it collides with the procedure `list`. You do `(apply g list)` and it will make a `struct` with the values from `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a transparent or [prefab](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structures.html#%28tech._prefab%29) struct, you can use [`struct->list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structutils.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct..rkt%29._struct-%7E3elist%29%29) to convert it to a list:

```lisp
> (struct g (a b c d) #:transparent)
> (define foo (g 1 6 5 4))
> (struct->list foo)
'(1 6 5 4)
```